# "You have an error in your SQL syntax" при выполнении INSERT запроса

Tags: php, mysql

```
$okcar1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mycars(id_car,id_user,car,carname,speed) VALUES('".$_POST['idcar']."','".$data_user['id']."','".$auto_row['car']."','".$auto_row['carname']."','".$auto_row['speed']."' login='".$_SESSION['user']."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

выдает ошибку:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`login'`='John123')' at line 1
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 2):

Заменим все, что у вас подставляется на эрзац-величины.

```
"INSERT INTO mycars(id_car,id_user,car,carname,speed) VALUES('idcar_value','data_user_value','auto_row_value','carname_value','speed_value' login='user_value')"
```

Вот на это login='user_value' он и ругается. Потому что нельзя сюда такие выражения запихивать. Если вы хотели создать условие, добавьте where. Но точно ПОСЛЕ скобок.

Используйте, хотя бы, sprintf, чтобы проще было искать ошибки.

Comment: блин нечего не понятнно можеи полностью код написать чтобы работал

Comment: Вопрос в другом, какой WHERE в INSERT запросе? ;)

Comment: да блин все работало , ну ставит туда где например логин равняеться test , непонятно?

Comment: @dekameron, меня этот вопрос тоже волнует. =)

Comment: @anonymous_911_, нет, не понятно. Напишите подробнее и без блинов: они не улучшают читаемость и не способствуют пониманию.

Comment: извините я ошибся , прошу простить все заработало просто не внемательность

Comment: where ненужен

Answer (score 0):

```
$okcar1 = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO mycars(id_car,id_user,car,carname,speed, login) 
    VALUES(
        '".$_POST['idcar']."',
        '".$data_user['id']."',
        '".$auto_row['car']."',
        '".$auto_row['carname']."',
        '".$auto_row['speed']."',
        '".$_SESSION['user']."');"
    )or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: а где условие where?

Comment: Опишите словами, что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Answer (score -1):

```
$okcar1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
     mycars(id_car,id_user,car,carname,speed) 
     VALUES(
         '".$_POST['idcar']."',
         '".$data_user['id']."',
         '".$auto_row['car']."',
         '".$auto_row['carname']."',
         '".$auto_row['speed']."' **WHERE**
          login='".$_SESSION['user']."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Собственно просто добавь WHERE и будет счастье!

Comment: Вы уверены, что майскьюэль не подавится этим ключевым словом внутри VALUES()?!